# How to rebase a branch from previous fork in one command?

Tags: macos, shell, git, zsh, alias

So I'm trying to come up with a ZSH alias for Git that will rebase my current branch onto the branch it was originally derived (forked) from.

Examples:

Given the following branch names of `A` and `B`. If I create branch `B` by forking from `A` from time-to-time I would like to keep `B` up-to-date with `A`.

To do this manually I would usually do:

```
git rebase A
```

Which would repay the commits from the fork point on `B` on-top of `A`.

Given that I want a command to do this automatically for any branch I'm working on this is where I was heading:

```
git rebase --onto A {commit-hash-of-fork-point} B
```

I believe this command will give the fork point commit:

```
git merge-base --fork-point A B
```

So combining them:

```
git rebase --onto A $(git merge-base --fork-point A B) B
```

How can I write this as a generic alias for ZSH so that I can just call `gr` and it will determine the current branch, and the forked branch etc.

Comment: You cannot specify parameters in aliases, but you can use a function instead: `gr() { git rebase --onto "$1" $(git merge-base --fork-point "$1" "$2") "$2" }`. This would be defined in one of the start-up files.

Comment: How would I turn that into an alias and then call it?

Comment: You don't call it as an alias: you call it as a function, though the call will look the same; eg `gr A B` will expand into your final, combined command.

Comment: @AFH, could you add that as an answer?